# Job Assignments and bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

This excerpt is from "Introduction to Graph Theory" by Douglas B. West, page 4, section 1.1.9. Example

We have m jobs and n people, but not all people are qualified for all jobs. Can we fill the jobs with qualified people? We model this using a simple graph H with vertices for the jobs and people; job j is adjacent to person p if p can do j

Each job is to be filled by exactly one person, and each person can hold at most one of the jobs. Thus we seek m pairwise disjoint edges in H ( viewing edges as pairs of vertices ).

It can't be done in the graph below:

[image]

This is what the books says, my question is: Isn't the graph already a bipartite graph? because it diagram shows that the vertex set can be divided into partite sets?

My speculation is that, it indeed is a bipartite graph but this bipartite graph does not fit in our context of each person holding atmost one job that's why the books says "it can't be done in the graph below"

Comment: "It can't be done" refers probably to the fact that in the example in the picture it is impossible to find the assignment of all jobs to people, or in other words the answer to the question "Can we fill all the jobs with qualified people" in this case is no.

Comment: Aha, makes sense! Thank you!